# NULL's missing while move from Anydac to Firedac

Tags: delphi, firedac, anydac

I'm moving code from `Delphi 2007 + AnyDac` to `Delphi XE4 + FireDac`. In `AnyDac` case all empty strings were stored like `NULL`, and in `FireDac` all empty strings are stored like empty string `''`.

I need to go back to NULL's. What is the best way of doing that? I store to DB using params:

```
ADQuery.Params.ParamByName('Code').Value :=Code;
```

Comment: You say "stored", but this is controlled by database. What's your database?

Comment: @Marcus, primarily by a dataset control itself (see the post below)... After then it's upon database how it stores.

Comment: @TLama, if you assume the only point of access to the database is your dataset control. There's room for a more complete answer if OP answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include (set it to True in the Object Inspector) the [`StrsEmpty2Null`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFormatOptions.StrsEmpty2Null) option to the `FormatOptions` of your dataset object. The reference says (emphasized by me):

> **Controls the conversion of zero-length string values to NULL value**. Use the StrsEmpty2Null property to control whether FireDAC
>   should convert string values with zero length to NULL value (True) or
>   not (False). **The default value is False**.